# Разделение аргументов через запятую discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Вообщем, у меня есть бот дискорд, который генерирует мемы с одной строки. Как сделать так, чтобы после команды meme первый аргумент был **first**, далее точка с запятой и второй аргумент **second**.

```
async def meme(ctx, *first, *second):
    img("hiq", first, second)
    await ctx.send('', file=discord.File('hiq.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так ?

```
async def meme(ctx, *, string):
    first=string.split(';')[0]
    second=string.split(';')[1]
    img("hiq", first, second)
    await ctx.send('', file=discord.File('hiq.jpg'))
```

Comment: first и second это переменные, которые задаются в функции meme, мне нужно, что бы, при выполнении команды meme привет1 привет1; привет2 привет2. В переменную first записывалась строка "привет1 привет1", а в second "привет2 привет2"

Comment: @GriteLine исправил код

Comment: твой код принимает только слово, а строка? То есть, возможность пробелов между строкой до ; и после

Comment: если речь о возможности вызвать функцию так `meme(ctx, 'Hello, my name is Nick ; My answer ')` то код сработает

Comment: не работает. Ошибка: discord.ext.commands.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: так это ошибка не в разделении строки а в вызове `ctx.send`.

Comment: так ведь с словами работает всё

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103998/discussion-between-n1tr0xs-and-grite-line).